# Random skill ups while running around in Rune Factory ToD

Tags: rune-factory-tod

I was just wondering what the random skill ups you get while running around in Rune Factory ToD are for? or what they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Walking is actually a skill in ToD. Walking around increases that stat. In other words, leading a healthy lifestyle (like walking around, eating, sleeping) makes you healthier.

Comment: What effect does being healthier have in the game? More HP/RP? Quicker experience?

Comment: It affects your various skills - walking, eating, sleeping, etc. and they have different bonuses (from what I could tell).